# Logstash Grok filter getting multiple values per match

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a server that sends access logs over to logstash in a custom log format, and am using logstash to filter these logs and send them to Elastisearch.

A log line looks something like this:

```
0.0.0.0 - GET / 200 - 29771 3 ms ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\n
```

And gets parsed using this grok filter:

```
grok {
  match => [ 
    "message", "%{IP:remote_host} %{USER:remote_user} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:requested_uri} %{NUMBER:status_code} - %{NUMBER:content_length} %{NUMBER:elapsed_time:int} ms %{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}",
    "message", "%{IP:remote_host} - %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:requested_uri} %{NUMBER:status_code} - %{NUMBER:content_length} %{NUMBER:elapsed_time:int} ms %{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}",
    "message", "%{IP:remote_host} %{USER:remote_user} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:requested_uri} %{NUMBER:status_code} - - %{NUMBER:elapsed_time:int} ms %{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}",
    "message", "%{IP:remote_host} - %{WORD:method} %{URIPATHPARAM:requested_uri} %{NUMBER:status_code} - - %{NUMBER:elapsed_time:int} ms %{GREEDYDATA:user_agent}"
  ]
  add_field => { 
    "protocol" => "HTTP"
  }
}
```

The final log gets parsed into this object (with real IPs stubbed out, and other fields taken out):

```
{
  "_source": {
    "message": " 0.0.0.0 - GET / 200 - 29771 3 ms ELB-HealthChecker/1.0\n",
    "tags": [
      "bunyan"
    ],
    "@version": "1",
    "host": "0.0.0.0:0000",
    "remote_host": [
      "0.0.0.0",
      "0.0.0.0"
    ],
    "remote_user": [
      "-",
      "-"
    ],
    "method": [
      "GET",
      "GET"
    ],
    "requested_uri": [
      "/",
      "/"
    ],
    "status_code": [
      "200",
      "200"
    ],
    "content_length": [
      "29771",
      "29771"
    ],
    "elapsed_time": [
      "3",
      3
    ],
    "user_agent": [
      "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0",
      "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0"
    ],
    "protocol": [
      "HTTP",
      "HTTP"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting multiple matches per log? Shouldn't Grok be breaking on the first match that successfully parses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you have multiple config files that are being loaded.  If you look at the output, specifically the `elapsed_time` shows up as both an integer and a string.  From the config file you've provided, that's not possible since you have `:int` on anything that matches `elapsed_time`.

Comment: hm.. that might be the case. Good catch, will check.