# logstash grok not working for some of the dataset

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, kibana-6

This is just related to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142085/how-to-write-custom-grok-for-logstash/54161210) where i'm using the below grok filter to dissect the data to be visualize into kibana, below is what i'm using into my logstash conf file and working for the data as desired but today I got into a situation where its not filtering the data as desired.

Correct visual at Kibana are like:

> **received_at**:February 1st 2019, 21:00:04.105 float:0.5, 0.0 **type**:rmlog **Hostname**:dba- foxon93 Date:19/02/01 **User_1**:dv_vxehw **@version**:1 **Hour_since**:06 **Command**:rm -rf  /data/rg/log

grok filter in logstash conf file:

```
 match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:Hostname},%{DATE:Date},%{HOUR:Hour_since}:%{MINUTE:Mins_since},%{NUMBER}-%{WORD},%{USER:User_1},%{USER:User_2} %{NUMBER:Pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:Num_1} %{NUMBER:Num_2} %{DATA} %{HOUR:hour2}:%{MINUTE:minute2} %{HOUR:hour3}:%{MINUTE:minute3} %{GREEDYDATA:Command}" }
```

### My logstash conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/data/mylogs/*.txt" ]
    start_position => beginning
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    type => "tac"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "tac" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{HOSTNAME:Hostname},%{DATE:Date},%{HOUR:Hour_since}:%{MINUTE:Mins_since},%{NUMBER}-%{WORD},%{USER:User_1},%{USER:User_2} %{NUMBER:Pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:Num_1} %{NUMBER:Num_2} %{DATA} %{HOUR:hour2}:%{MINUTE:minute2} %{HOUR:hour3}:%{MINUTE:minute3} %{GREEDYDATA:Command}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      remove_field => [ "@version", "host", "message", "_type", "_index", "_score" ]
   }
 }
}

output {
        if [type] == "rmlog" {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                manage_template => false
                index => "tac-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
 }
}
```

Below is the new data which is getting processed but i'm not getting the **Hostname** , **Command** etc fields for this data.

```
dbproj01,19/02/01,00:04,23-hrs,cvial,cvial 120804 0.0 0.0 106096 1200 pts/90 S Jan30 0:00 /bin/sh -c /bin/rm -f ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.cxt ../../../../../../
tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.toc ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.aux ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.ini ; (CUR_DIR=`pwd` ;
 cd ../../../../obj/linux-x86-64/optimize/bin/virtuoso ; ${CUR_DIR}/../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/bin/virtuoso -ilLoadIL hBrowserBuildContext.il -log hBrowserBuildContext.log -nograph && [ `/bi
n/grep -c Error hBrowserBuildContext.log` = 0 ]) || (echo '*** Error: Failed to build hBrowser context.' ; /bin/rm -f ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.cxt ../../../../..
/../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.toc ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.aux ../../../../../../tools.lnx86/dfII/etc/context/64bit/hBrowser.ini ; exit 1),/pro
j/cvial/WS/BUNGEE/REBASE_190120-138_2/tools.lnx86/dfII/group/bin/src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your issue in `%{HOUR:hour2}:%{MINUTE:minute2}` value as it returns as date `Jan30` not time and also its included in `%{DATA}` section.

Below pattern will handle it

```
%{HOSTNAME:Hostname},%{DATE:Date},%{HOUR:Hour_since}:%{MINUTE:Mins_since},%{NUMBER}-%{WORD},%{USER:User_1},%{USER:User_2} %{NUMBER:Pid} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:float} %{NUMBER:Num_1} %{NUMBER:Num_2} %{DATA} (?:%{HOUR:hour2}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:minute2}|) (?:%{HOUR:hour3}:|)(?:%{MINUTE:minute3}|)%{GREEDYDATA:Command}
```

Also you can use [Grok Debug](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) for pattern test.

Comment: @ Wael,  thanks for the quick catch, Is there is way do have a condition if the current grok do not match then use another grok.

Comment: Yo can try `if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] { // another grok } }`

Comment: @krock1516 check also my answer for needed pattern

Comment: @krock1516 You can also use more than one grok pattern in one grok filter. The filter will try to match the field with the patterns until one of them matches. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30266104/6113627) for an example on hos to do it.